# What's the difference between next/router and next/navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In Next.js, I know both `next/router` and `next/navigation` have a `useRouter()` hook, but the returned objects are different. Why does Next.js have the same hook on two routing packages?

Answer (score 25):

The [`useRouter`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router) from `next/router` is to be used in the [`pages`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) folder, the initial way of setting up routes in Next.js. Since `v13`, they introduced a new directory called [`app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) (used when you say Yes to the last question shown in the below image), built on top of [Server Components](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#server-components), where you define routes differently and use [`useRouter`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router) from `next/navigation`:

[image]

A quote from the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs):

> At the top of the sidebar, you'll notice a dropdown menu that allows you to switch between the **App Router** the **Pages Router** features. Since there are features that are unique to each directory, it's important to keep track of which tab is selected.

As you can see on the left, you can choose the type of router you want to get the relevant doc:

[image]

Comment: I think the confusion comes from: does this mean that `next/router` is obsolete if you are using app dir or it should be used for client side components while next/navigation for server side ones ?

Comment: No, `next/router` is not obsolete. But it can only be used within the `pages` router.

Answer (score 5):

**next/router** and **next/navigation** both are similar and serve the same purpose.

- **next/router**
  - next/router is the oldest package for navigation. It is more lightweight and built for basic routing needs.
  - It is useful for simple applications and applications that don't use modern features of nextJS
- **next/navigation**
  - It is the newer routing package for routing.
  - It is a more powerful package that provides several advanced features, such as App router, Link, useRouter hook etc.

In general, you should use next/navigation for nextJs applications. However, if you have a simple application or an application that does not need the advanced features of next/navigation, then you can still use next/router. It still supported by nextJs.

Comment: Can you support these claims or is it personal opinion? Can I just choose between the two depending on the current usecase at hand?

Answer (score -1):

Both next/router and next/navigation are packages in the Next.js framework and is used for routing and navigation functionality.
But yes, there are difference in their feature and use cases.

**next/router:**

- It's older package used in nextjs version prior to 13 and it only support `pages` directory. It does not contains the advanced feature offered by **next/navigation**

**next/navigation**

- This is new package introduced in Nextjs 13 and it works with `app` directory. It provides a more modern and flexible navigation solution and it's more recommended option.

In summary, **next/router** is an older package used for navigation in older versions of Next.js, while **next/navigation** is a newer and more advanced package which is introduced in Next.js 13. If you're using an older version of Next.js, you'll need to use **next/router**. If you're on Next.js 13 or later, it's recommended to use **next/navigation** for better performance and a more modern navigation experience.