# NextJS Internationalization (i18n) Routing: locale getting undefined

Tags: reactjs, next.js, frontend, internationalization, i18next

I'm trying to learn [Next.js Internationalization (i18n) Routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/internationalization) for my personal website. However, the locale, locales, and default locale values are getting as undefined. (I'm using the latest version of Next.js)

Here is my files:

**next.config.js:**

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ["tr", "en"],
    defaultLocale: "tr",
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

**locales/tr.js:**

```
export default {
  hello: "Merhaba dünya!",
};
```

**locales/en.js:**

```
export default {
  hello: "Hello world!",
};
```

**app/page.js:**

```
"use client";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function Home() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { locale, locales, defaultLocale } = router;
  console.log("Locales:", locale, locales, defaultLocale);
  console.log(router);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
      <p>Current locale: {locale}</p>
      <p>Default locale: {defaultLocale}</p>
      <p>Configured locales: {JSON.stringify(locales)}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**I tried to get information using console.log. The print is as follows:**
[The print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFJKr.png)

**Lastly, package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.45.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.12",
    "next": "13.4.12",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  }
}
```

I can't find where I made a mistake. Please help me fix it.

Answer (score 0):

one thing I noticed is that you are confusing routers. There is a next/navigation.js as well as a next/router.js - both of which can deconstruct to useRouter. Only the next/router has locale - next/navigation.js does not have locale.

The solution is not to just change your import statement though, I just tried that and it leads to a "Error: NextRouter was not mounted. [https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-router-not-mounted"](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-router-not-mounted%22) error.

Right now I'm still figuring the solution out too, but the answer is probably here https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/internationalization

Comment: good point. See also: [What's the difference between next/router and next/navigation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76285831/whats-the-difference-between-next-router-and-next-navigation)