# Next JS useRouter.push() is not routing correctly

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm working on a web page that lets users Log In/Sign In and then they are redirected to a `user/[id]` where the `id` is a unique identifier they have on the database, the process to getting the user information is working fine, but when I try to redirect them back to the root `/` page after they have been logged out (sessions destroyed) but instead the page is reloaded but there is no user data displaying.

At first I thought this was a problem with my index page because I used a `useEffect` hook to redirect the user to the `user/[id]` page if there is an active session, but I already tested by commenting the `router.push()` function to prevent it from redirecting and the empty user page is still appearing after trying to log out.

The stricture of the project is the following:

```
src
  pages
    api
      user
        [id].ts
      logout.ts
    user
      [id].tsx
    index.tsx
```

My `index.tsx` page

```
import {useEffect} from 'react';
import { Button, Card, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';


export default function Home() {
  const router = useRouter()
  

  useEffect(() =>{
      sessionHandler();
  },[])

    const sessionHandler = async () => {
        const session = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/session`)
        if(session.data !== null){
            router.push(`/user/${session.data.id}`)
        }
        
    }
  
  return(
      <Card className='text-center'>
          <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Bienvenido al sistema de Clientes de National Unity</Card.Title>
              <Card.Text>Selecciona una de las opciones para ingresar al sistema</Card.Text>
              <Row className='my-2'>
                  <Button variant='primary' onClick={() => router.push('/logIn')}>Iniciar Sesión</Button>
              </Row>
              <Row className='my-2'>
                  <Button variant='secondary' onClick={() => router.push('/signin')}>Registrarse</Button>
              </Row>
              <Row className='my-2'>
                  <Button variant='info'>Ingresar como Invitado</Button>
              </Row>
          </Card.Body>
      </Card>
  )
}
```

The `user/[id].tsx` page

```
import  { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { Form, Button, Card, Row, Container, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap'
import axios from "axios"
import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import { signOut } from "next-auth/react";

function UserPage(){
    const router = useRouter()
    const searchParams = useSearchParams()
    
    const id = searchParams.get('id');
    
    const [user, setUser] = useState({
        id: null,
        name: null,
        email: null,
    })
    
    
    const getUser = async () =>{
        
        const result = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/user/${id}`)  
            
        setUser(result.data.user)
    }

    useEffect(() =>{
        getUser()
    },[])
    const handleDestroySession = async () =>{
        const result = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/logout')
    }

    //Función para log out
    const logOut = async () =>{
        await handleDestroySession()
        router.push('/');
    }


    return(
        <Container>
            <Card>
                <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title className='mb-3'>{user.name}</Card.Title>
                    <Card.Text className='mb-3'>{user.email}</Card.Text>
                    <Button onClick={logOut}>Log Out</Button>
                </Card.Body>
            </Card> 
        </Container>   
    )
}

export default UserPage
```

The user session is correctly getting destroyed on the Application tab of my browser's Dev Tools, so that is not the problem.

I have other router calls for general navigation on the project because I have other pages, and it is working fine on those, so the problem is specifically on this page.

If anyone has any idea what could be causing this issue I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Which version of Next.js are you using? Are you using the pages or app directory?

Comment: I'm on Next 13.4.19 and I'm using a pages directory, I can update the question to show the structure if you need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution. When looking at the documentation for Next-Auth I found that the SignOut method has an option to redirect to a specified url after signing out

```
const logOut = async () =>{
    signOut({callbackUrl: 'http://localhost:3000'})
}
```

This correctly redirects to the index page of the project

[Documentation](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#signout)

Answer (score 0):

Since everything else looks good to me: try using the Next 12 router (imported from "**next/router"**) instead of the one from "next/navigation"). The one you are using is intended for server components, so there might be some weird stuff happening, since you are using the *pages* structure.

I couldn't find much info in Vercel's documentation, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76285831/whats-the-difference-between-next-router-and-next-navigation)'s a related question. Let me know how it goes!